# Serie de números multiplicados por 2 en Python

Tags: python

Como puedo hacer para que un número se repita varias veces en una serie? Debo realizar un programa que imprima la siguiente serie para "n" números:

2,2,4,2,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,..... (n=10)

La primera iteración debe devolver 2, la segunda 2,4, la tercera 2,4,6 y así.

Lo que intenté fue esto:

```
n=10
a=[]
i=1
while(i<=n):
    b=i*2
    print(b,",",end=" ")
    if(i<n):
        print(b,",",end=" ")
    i= i+1
    a.append(i)
print()
```

Por favor ayuda, soy nuevo en programación.

Comment: Podrías irlos guardando en una estructura de datos a medida que los generas, con eso generas uno nuevo en cada iteración y la tarea sería sólo "volver a imprimir el listado completo".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solucion mas simple basado en tu codigo seria esta.

```
n=10
a=[]
i=1
while(i<=n):
    b=i*2
    a.append(str(b))
    print(",".join(a))
    i+=1
```

Resultado:

```
2
2,4
2,4,6
2,4,6,8
2,4,6,8,10
2,4,6,8,10,12
2,4,6,8,10,12,14
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
```

Entonces ya solo tendrias que concatenar la respuesta de este modo.

```
n=10
a=[]
i=1
result = ""
while(i<=n):
    b=i*2
    a.append(str(b))
    i+=1
    result = result + ",".join(a) + ("," if i<=n else "")
    
print(result)
```

Donde el resultado es:

```
2,2,4,2,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
```

Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes resolver con un doble ciclo `for`, el primero para obtener las `n` subsecuencias y el segundo para cada estas últimas:

```
n = 10
lista = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
  for j in range(1, i+1):
    lista.append(2 * j)

print(lista)

[2, 
 2, 4, 
 2, 4, 6, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 
 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es ir guardando los datos cuando se genera el numero y en la próxima iteración imprimimos lo que hay guardado más el nuevo numero y así n veces

```py
n=10
nums=[] #aqui vamos a guardar los numeros generados
i=1
while i<=n:
    num = i*2 #calculamos el numero
    numeros = ','.join(nums)+f',{num}' #generamos el print
    print(numeros, end=",") #imprimimos
    nums.append(str(num)) #guardamos
    i+=1
```

**resultado**

```
,2,2,4,2,4,6,2,4,6,8,2,4,6,8,10,2,4,6,8,10,12,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20
```

EL único problema es la coma `,` que aparece al inicio :/